# Coq: Unification fails with record

Tags: record, coq, dependent-type, unification

Here is a small instance of my problem:

```
Record ord : Type := mk_ord
{ tord: Type;
  ole: tord -> tord -> Prop;
}.

Definition onat := mk_ord nat le.

Definition singl (O : ord) (e : tord O) : list (tord O) :=
  cons e nil.

Lemma singl_len :
  forall (O : ord) (e : tord O), length (singl O e) = 1.
Proof.
  trivial.
Qed.

Example unif : length (singl onat 2) = 1.
Proof.
  Set Printing All.
  simpl (tord _). (* [tord nat] changes to [nat] *)
  Fail rewrite singl_len.
Abort.
```

I guess that the rewriting fails while trying to unify `tord ?O` (in the lemma) with `nat` (in the goal).

But `?O` will be set to `onat` anyway because of the `singl onat 2` matched in the goal, so why does it fail to convert `tord onat` to `nat` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one solution for `?O`, not only `onat`, that would make this rewrite valid, so there's a legitimate reason for it to fail.

```
(* ... *)

Definition onat2 := mk_ord nat gt.  (* gt instead of le *)

Example unif : length (singl onat 2) = 1.
Proof. apply (singl_len onat2). Qed. (* onat and onat2 both work here *)
```

In general the unifier in `rewrite` is very syntactic, so it's best to not rely on it unfolding definitions to make proofs more predictable.

However in this case the problem is to solve the equation `tord ?O = nat`, which does not have a unique solution, as shown above, but we can declare a *canonical* solution for it, because morally we do want to associate the `nat` type with the `onat` record. This is done by using the `Canonical` keyword when defining the `onat` record.

```
Canonical onat := mk_ord nat le.   (* solves  tord ?O = nat  with  ?O := onat *)

(* ... *)

Example unif : length (singl onat 2) = 1.
Proof.
  Set Printing All.
  simpl (tord _). (* [tord nat] changes to [nat] *)
  rewrite singl_len.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```